# Kafka: How to achieve Round Robin Partition in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am new in kafka. My requirement is, I have two partition for example Partition-0 and Partition-1 and I have list of values which also contains KEY value. I want to store data according to my key like key-1 will goes to Partition-0, key-2 will goes to Partition-1. With old API there is way to achieve like we need to implement Partition interface but how I can do this with new API. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new producer you may also implement `Partitioner` interface (https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Partitioner.java) to achieve round-robin distribution.

You can use `DefaultPartitioner` for reference - https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/DefaultPartitioner.java

Answer (score 3):

If you want round-robin behaviour, just do not pass key when writing to Producer and `DefaultPartitioner` will do the job for you. You do not need to write a custom implementation. From the javadocs:

```
/**
 * The default partitioning strategy:
 * <ul>
 * <li>If a partition is specified in the record, use it
 * <li>If no partition is specified but a key is present choose a partition based on a hash of the key
 * <li>If no partition or key is present choose a partition in a round-robin fashion
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can produce to kafka in round robin fashion by overriding the [default  partitioner](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Partitioner.html) of the kafka producer.

A pseudo implementation

```
class RRPartitioner():
      def __init__():
            # Using topic metadata get total number of partitions
            self.total_partitions = client[topic].get_number_partitions()
            self.part_offset = 0

      def partitioner(self, key, msg):
          if self.part_offset > self.total_partitions:
              self.part_offset = 0
              return self.part_offset
          else:
              self.part_offset += 1
              return self.part_offset
```

Above implementation it's pure round-robin, if you want the messages to be ordered according to keys and have round-robin you will have to do more in the custom partitioner.

Comment: This is the simplest solution but it won't work if you add a partition at runtime, which is a completely valid case

Comment: True..you will have to restart producer or poll periodically for metadata changes. Bust most existing keyed producers will have same issue IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

As of Kafka 2.4.0 you have an option to do "Always" Roundrobin.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3333

Comment: @AlpcanYıldız     Not sure what you mean by Kafka streams properties, but it's a producer-centric config. You can read about KafkaStreams which says that it's using a plain producer underneath to write processed stream data - https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.3/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.java

Comment: I actually wanted to ask, in kafka stream properties can I use default partitioner,? I understand that kafka streams use default plain partitioner. For example I may say that         props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STANDBY_REPLICAS_CONFIG, streamingConfig.getStandbyReplicas()). Because it is a StreamsConfig. But can I say         props.put(Pro.NUM_STANDBY_REPLICAS_CONFIG, streamingConfig.getStandbyReplicas()); But can I use this one ?          props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, RoundRobinPartitioner.class).

Comment: Can you please check my question ? Because Matthias says I can't use this configuration but actually I can (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59645127/kafka-streams-roundrobinpartitioner/59658438?noredirect=1#comment105539367_59658438). If I use RoundRobinPartitioner with 2.4 client and 2.2 versioned kafka, producer use roundrobin setting but I can't use all internal topic's partitions. It distribute my message like ~30 or ~40 partitions over 50 partitions

Comment: @AlpcanYıldız       What Matthias meant was - You cannot use it directly. I suggest you check DefaultStreamPartitioner class and see how it's using an instance of `DefaultPartitioner` internally. Your custom implementation would simply implement `StreamPartitioner` and use the `RoundRobinPartitioner` internally to do it. A word of caution - be wary of ordering.

Also, he did mention exactly this in the second paragraph. Bottom line - you cannot use it directly via Producer.properties

Comment: If I can't use with like this, do you know how I can achieve this so all my kafka-dsl topology use round robin partitioner in all internal topics?