# Kafka Streams RoundRobinPartitioner

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I wrote a kafka streams code that uses kafka 2.4 kafka client version and kafka 2.2 server version. I have 50 partition on my topic & internal topic.

My kafka stream code has selectKey() DSL operation and I have 2 million of record using same KEY. In the stream configuration, I have done

`props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, RoundRobinPartitioner.class);`

So that I am able to use different partitions with the exactly same key. If I dont use Round Robin as expected all my messages go to same partition.

Everything is ok untill now but I realized that; when I use RoundRobinPartitioner class my messages go like ~40 partitions. 10 partition is in the idle state. I wonder what am I missing ? It should use 50 of them about 2 million of records right?

```
      final KStream<String, IdListExportMessage> exportedDeviceIdsStream =
            builder.stream("deviceIds");

        // k: appId::deviceId, v: device
        final KTable<String, Device> deviceTable = builder.table(
            "device",
            Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), deviceSerde)
        );
            // Some DSL operations
            .join(
                deviceTable,
                (exportedDevice, device) -> {
                    exportedDevice.setDevice(device);

                    return exportedDevice;
                },
                Joined.with(Serdes.String(), exportedDeviceSerde, deviceSerde)
            )
            .selectKey((deviceId, exportedDevice) -> exportedDevice.getDevice().getId())
            .to("bulk_consumer");
```

And

```
   props.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, /tmp/kafka-streams);
   props.put(StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG, 3);
   props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STANDBY_REPLICAS_CONFIG, 2);
   props.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 100);
   props.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, EXACTLY_ONCE);
   props.put("num.stream.threads", 10);
   props.put("application.id", applicationId);
```

RoundRobinPartitioner.java

```
public class RoundRobinPartitioner implements Partitioner {
    private final ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicInteger> topicCounterMap = new ConcurrentHashMap();

    public RoundRobinPartitioner() {
    }

    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs) {
    }

    public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes, Cluster cluster) {
        List<PartitionInfo> partitions = cluster.partitionsForTopic(topic);
        int numPartitions = partitions.size();
        int nextValue = this.nextValue(topic);
        List<PartitionInfo> availablePartitions = cluster.availablePartitionsForTopic(topic);
        if (!availablePartitions.isEmpty()) {
            int part = Utils.toPositive(nextValue) % availablePartitions.size();
            return ((PartitionInfo)availablePartitions.get(part)).partition();
        } else {
            return Utils.toPositive(nextValue) % numPartitions;
        }
    }

    private int nextValue(String topic) {
        AtomicInteger counter = (AtomicInteger)this.topicCounterMap.computeIfAbsent(topic, (k) -> {
            return new AtomicInteger(0);
        });
        return counter.getAndIncrement();
    }

    public void close() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u share the code snippet of producer writing data to the Kafka cluster?

Comment: Please show your partitioner code

Comment: Hello, I have edited my question

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the partitioning using `ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG` configuration -- this only works for the plain producer.

In Kafka Streams, you need to implement the interface `StreamsPartitioner` and pass your implementation into corresponding operators, e.g., `to("topic", Produced.streamPartitioner(new MyPartitioner())`.

Comment: Thank you sir, but actually If I use ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, I see that only one key is distributed internal topic partitions, and my only internal topic is created by selectKey() part. I can see the lags between partitions, if I don't use this property all my messages go to same partition. but I can't do what you say in selectKey part and actually .to() part, expecting me to Produced.with(key, value) :/

Comment: My bad, the method name is `Produced.streamPartitioner(StreamPartitioner<? super K,? super V> partitioner)` -> https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Produced.html#streamPartitioner-org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.StreamPartitioner-

Comment: Yep, that is ok for to("topic", Produced.streamPartitioner(new MyPartitioner()), but does not work for .selectKey(). But still, props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, RoundRobinPartitioner.class); works for selectKey part. Just did not understand why I can not use all partitions but can use the ~40 partitions

Comment: You don't need it for `selectKey()` because selectKey() does not write into a topic. -- Not sure what you mean by `But still, props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, RoundRobinPartitioner.class); works for selectKey part` -- what I am frankly wondering thought it, what the config has any effect -- Kafka Streams should ignore it completely and behave the exact some way with or without it...?

Comment: Does not selectKey() write to internal topic ? Because I am changing the key.. When I follow the internal topics without ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, RoundRobinPartitioner.class, I can see the all messages go same partition. But when I configure this property I can see also messages are distributed to internal topic partitions but like I said not all of them.

Comment: `Does not selectKey() write to internal topic?` -> No. It only "marks the streams" that the key was changed -- only if you go a groupByKey or join downstream a repartition topic would be created. Ie, you can consider repartitioning to be "lazy": it's only done if necessary and changing the key itself does not require to repartition.

Comment: Is there a way to use RoundRobinPartitioner in internal topics by implementing StreamPartitioner ? Or I can't use my partitioner except to() or through()..

Comment: Ohhh I see.. DefaultStreamPartitioner has a attribute which is     private final DefaultPartitioner defaultPartitioner. So actually when I configure my property as: props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, RoundRobinPartitioner.class), it actually use RoundRobinPartitioner instead of DefaultPartitioner right? Becuase overrided method in StreamPartitioner partition method is consist of         return this.defaultPartitioner.partition(topic, key, keyBytes, value, (byte[])null, this.cluster);
. But why does this use my ~30 partitions instead of all my partitions (50). :(