# Kafka Streams Custom Partitioner for internal topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to know that in Kafka Streams properties, am I able to write my own producer? Can I use my own Producer Partitioner and send kafka messages to internal topics by kafka streams by my own Producer ?

I know that I can use my partitioner in

```
to("topic", Produced.streamPartitioner(new MyPartitioner())
```

but I want to use it also in internal topics.

Comment: Can you clarify why you need to care about the internal topics?

Comment: Beucase I am using only a key. I mean just one unique key and all my ~2milliyon of records use that key. That is why all my messages go to same partition because of key. I want to distribute my messages and I need to distribute with exactly one key. That is why I am asking

Comment: Have you tried adding `partitioner.class` to the `Properties` of your Kafka Streams?

Comment: Yes I did for KafkaStreams props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, RoundRobinPartitioner.class). But it is not StreamsConfig, it is a ProducerConfig. When I configure like this my messages are distributed between partitions. I have 50 partitions but with this configuration it distributes my messages like ~30 partitions over 2 million of records. I did not understand why. I am using kafka client 2.4 and kafka 2.2 version

Comment: Using ProducerConfig is perfectly fine. Even says so in the documentation. However, [Matias might be right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59658438/2308683) that it cannot be set by Steams applications in particular

Comment: How did you find this :) Yes I am not %100 sure that it applies or not :/